# StopPropogation() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigationbar

I am coding a multilevel drop down menu in which when the parent is hovered, the submenu drops down with JQuery `fadeIn()`. But the effect is getting propagated to the child elements. They are also having `fadeIn()` when hovered on. The code is

HTML

```
<nav>
<ul id="headnav">
    <li> <a class="sliding-middle-out" href="index.php"> ABOUT </a> </li>
    <li> <a class="sliding-middle-out" href="practice.php"> PRACTICE </a> </li>
    <li> <a class="sliding-middle-out" href="research.php"> RESEARCH </a> 
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="papers.php"> Papers </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="articles.php"> Articles </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="phdstudents.php"> PhD Students </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="presentations.php"> Presentations </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('nav > ul > li > ul').hide();
    $('nav > ul > li').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('ul').fadeIn(400);
    },function() {
        $(this).find('ul').fadeOut(400);
    }); 

});
```

CSS

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
    min-width:30%;
    float:right;
    right:12%;
    top: 16%;
  }

  nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  nav ul li a{
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  }

  nav ul li ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    margin-left:-35%;
    margin-top:7%;
  }

  nav ul li ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width:10px;
  }

  nav ul li ul li a {
    color:#7f8c8d;
  }
```

When you hover your mouse over the child elements, they again `fadeIn()`. I tried `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` but none of them are working.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Show the submenu on hovering over the outer li, but hide it on leaving the inner ul:

```
$('nav > ul > li').mouseenter(function(e) {
    $(this).find('ul').fadeIn(400);
});
$('nav > ul > li > ul').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(400);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mava7btt/3/

Comment: While it might work (didn't test it), the  correct counterpart of `mouseleave`  is not `hover` but `mouseenter`. `.hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )` is used if you want to register the _enter_ and _leave_  callback at once.

Comment: Could you check the code again? Now the drop down is shown as default, without even hovering.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. But now I can leave the submenu open until I hover out of the sub UL. If I move my mouse along the upper side of the parent LI without hovering the faded in submenu, they will remain visible, till I hover them and `mouseleave` again.